# Getting corrupted information from mongoDB.

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Im using Spring 3.2.5 and pring data for mongodb 1.3.2. now I decided to use org.apache.commons.collections4.queue.CircularFifoQueue http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html#CircularFifoQueue(java.util.Collection)

I set its size to some value and save in mongo (using spring data repository). when I load it back from mongo it always get size = 32.

Way is that?

Comment: Some code perhaps? We cannot see what is causing the problem by your current question format.

Comment: The CircularFifoQueue [default size](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html#CircularFifoQueue()) is 32. As the default constructer gets invoked this value will automatically be applied. It would help to see what actually get stored in mongodb using a CircularFifoQueue. But you might  try registering a [custom reading converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/mongo.core.html#mongo.custom-converters.reader).